# CSS3 number matching selector

Tags: html, css, attributes, numbers, css-selectors

Sorry for the strange subject of the question, but I haven't got a clue how to name it smarter. I'm forced (...) to work on a system that is building forms. If input was filled wrong (by the user, but I'm giving an example with value to illustrate it):

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa"> 
<!-- aaa is of course not a valid email -->
```

after posting, the system add new attribute to this input:

```
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa" data-error="error1">
```

There are few type of errors (error1-error4) which correlates to: to short, to long, not regex matching, etc, but this is not important. What is important that data-error="error0" means no error (success).

---

**I'm trying to style this input. So I need an universal selector that works for:**

```
input[data-error="error1"] {box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00;}
input[data-error="error2"] {box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00;}
input[data-error="error3"] {box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00;}
input[data-error="error4"] {box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00;}
```

**And not work for:**

```
input[data-error="error0"] {box-shadow: none;}
```

---

I found an ugly solution. I style every input as the error one, and restyle only the `error0` input as not the error one. But first of all, the data-error attribute is added only after posting, and second of all this is a very ugly workaround.

I hope everything is clear, and this is possible.

---

PS. I can somehow force the system to output only number: `data-error="0"`, `data-error="1"`, ...

If this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following selector:

```
input[data-error^="error"]:not([data-error="error0"]) {}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s81xoxhe/)

It makes use of the [`[attr^=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) attribute selector, which

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value". [(reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

The `:not()` pseudo class is used to negate the selector `[data-error="error0"]`.

```css
input[data-error^="error"]:not([data-error="error0"]) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa" data-error="error0"/> 
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa" data-error="error1"/>
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa" data-error="error2"/> 
<input type="email" name="email" value="aaa" data-error="error3"/>
```

Comment: WOW. Impressive. I never thought that I can merge it like that +1. I must wait 11 minutes to accept. Thx for your help, and link update. Hope it will help someone in the future...

Comment: Thanks for links, and full commentary. It is really helpful, however the only thing that I missed is the thing that it is possible to merge logical querys in CSS. Thanks a lot, great resource!

Comment: Mind that `:not()` only accepts simple selectors. That said, your own solution wasn't that bad really.

Comment: Similarly, and I'm commenting because I don't think it's worthy of another answer, it's possible to use: [`input[data-error^="error"]:not([data-error$="0"])`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s81xoxhe/1/) (although if the possible error messages/types exceed 10, 0-9, then the same rule would apply to 10, 20, 30, etc).

Comment: Yep, great work. Maybe You've got a clue, if there is a selector for strict number matching? For example match number between (3-5)? Or regex based selector? This is "on the margin" question. Thanks once more.

Comment: @Jacek: no, not in CSS unfortunately; regular expressions can be implemented in JavaScript (and its libraries), but not with *just HTML/CSS*.

Comment: So we must wait for CSS4 ;)... Best regards!

Comment: Don't bother waiting. The chances of it happening are *very* slim.